# Drivers for Intel devices are not loaded in 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, intel

I'm attempting to use Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell OptiPlex 5090 Micro computer, but none of the Intel devices are being detected and as such their drivers are not being loaded. I have no networking and am stuck using `nomodeset` for graphics.

Hardware probe of the machine: https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=db46c8694c

Output of `lspci -nnk`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9b53] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0a54]
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9bc8] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0a54]
    Kernel modules: i915
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43ed] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0a54]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:14.2 RAM memory [0500]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43ef] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0a54]
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43e8] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0a54]
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43e0] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0a54]
00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43d2] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0a54]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4384] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0a54]
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:f0c8] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0a54]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43a3] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0a54]
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43a4] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0a54]
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:15f9] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0a54]
```

Ubuntu 20.04 is a little better at least being able to use the ethernet controller:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9b53] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0a54]
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9bc8] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0a54]
    Kernel modules: i915
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43ed] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0a54]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
00:14.2 RAM memory [0500]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43ef] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0a54]
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43e8] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0a54]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43e0] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0a54]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43d2] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0a54]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4384] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0a54]
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:f0c8] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0a54]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43a3] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0a54]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43a4] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0a54]
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (14) I219-LM [8086:15f9] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Dell Ethernet Connection (14) I219-LM [1028:0a54]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
```

Other Linux distros such as Fedora 34 and SystemRescueCD behave similarly to 20.04, only being able to detect the network card and nothing else.

What are my options here? I've tried copying a `modprobe` alias from 20.04 to 18.04 to get the network card working but that didn't seem to work. I didn't really know what I was doing though, so maybe I did it incorrectly.

Is there any way to force Ubuntu to load the correct drivers?

Comment: "none of the Intel devices are being detected and as such their drivers are not being loaded." Which devices are not working as expected? What does this tell us? `lspci -nnk` Please edit your question to show the result.

Comment: @chili555 I have no networking and can't use graphics without `nomodeset`. You can also see that the devices are listed with the generic "Intel Corporation Device" name rather than the actual name of the device. I've added the output of `lspci -nnk`.

Comment: I still don’t understand. Every device in your readings that requires a driver has a kernel driver in use, including the ethernet. What do you think the “actual name of the device” ought to be?

Comment: No they don't, at least not the ethernet. Compare the output in the first block and the second block. In the second block, the kernel module "e1000e" is listed and the device is given the name "Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (14) I219-LM". The first block has no kernel module and just the name "Intel Corporation Device".

Comment: It clearly says: "Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e" Isn't the module loaded? `lsmod | grep e1000e` Are there any errors in the log? `sudo dmesg | grep -e enp -e e1000e` So far, there is nothing unusual or not entirely expected.

Comment: Ok do you not see that I have two code blocks in my post? The first code block is from Ubuntu 18.04 and does not have the line “Kernel modules: e1000e”. The second code block is from Ubuntu 20.04 which *does* have the Ethernet driver loaded, but still doesn’t load other drivers like for the graphics card or the ISA bridge.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127965/discussion-between-chili555-and-jm0).